# Way to make video-thumbnails generate from VLC instead of Totem?

Tags: vlc, totem, gstreamer, thumbnails

I'm suffering from problem that video-thumbnails do not appear in nautilus for some video files. I just found this bug [typefinding: some mpeg files are not identified as mpeg files](https://bugs.launchpad.net/gst-opencv/+bug/1012652) which seems to address the problem. I don't understand the specifics as reported in this bug report, but it sounds like it's a problem with Totem's interaction with Gstreamer.

Since all my videos play fine with VLC (and they don't all play with Totem), I don't use Totem very much. Is there a way to make VLC generate the video-thumbnails instead of having to rely on the buggy gstreamer/totem? I made VLC my default video player but this had no effect on the display of video-thumbnails. If Totem can't play the video file, then I get no thumbnail. But VLC can play the videos fine, so why can't VLC create a video-thumbnail for it?

Comment: There's `ffmpegthumbs` and `ffmpegthumbnailer` as alternatives to totem thumbnailer. I don't know of any vlc thumbnailer though. http://www.hecticgeek.com/2011/11/how-to-make-ffmpegthumbnailer-work-in-ubuntu-11-10-oneiric-ocelot/

Comment: Possible Duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/2608/nautilus-video-thumbnails-without-totem

Comment: @medigeek - as far as I know, ffmpeg is the back-end for vlc.

Comment: Does this work **Nautilus File Manager >> edit > Preferences >>Preview column >> Other Previewable files** >>show thumbnails to always / In Only files for smaller than ~Desired values from drop down menu.

Comment: Take a look into [this tutoriall](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=804537) on how to use `ffmpegthumbnailers` to generate video thumbs in nautilus. If you are not satisfied, try to change it to use `vlc` as the generator regarding [this](http://wiki.videolan.org/Talk:How_to_create_thumbnails) one.

Comment: Use ffmpegthumbnailers.  This question is answered [Here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2608/nautilus-video-thumbnails-without-totem)

Comment: Does this link help? I don't have a lot of expertise on this topic.[How to create thumbnails](http://wiki.videolan.org/How_to_create_thumbnails)

Answer (score 12):

First, make sure all the ffmpeg (the back of vlc) components you need are installed:

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg ffmpegthumbnailer gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg
```

Clear the thumbnail cache, with bleachbit, ubuntu tweak, or this command:

```
rm ~/.thumbnails/fail/gnome-thumbnail-factory/*
rm ~/.thumbnails/normal/*
```

Now we need to tell Ubuntu not to use totem, but to use ffmpeg instead.
`sudo nano /usr/share/thumbnailers/totem.thumbnailer` and replace all the ext in `totem.thumbnailer` with the following:

```
[Thumbnailer Entry]
TryExec=ffmpegthumbnailer
Exec=ffmpegthumbnailer -s %s -i %i -o %o -c png -f -t 10
MimeType=application/mxf;application/ogg;application/ram;application/sdp;application/vnd.ms-wpl;application/vnd.rn-realmedia;application/x-extension-m4a;application/x-extension-mp4;application/x-flash-video;application/x-matroska;application/x-netshow-channel;application/x-ogg;application/x-quicktimeplayer;application/x-shorten;image/vnd.rn-realpix;image/x-pict;misc/ultravox;text/x-google-video-pointer;video/3gpp;video/dv;video/fli;video/flv;video/mp2t;video/mp4;video/mp4v-es;video/mpeg;video/msvideo;video/ogg;video/quicktime;video/vivo;video/vnd.divx;video/vnd.rn-realvideo;video/vnd.vivo;video/webm;video/x-anim;video/x-avi;video/x-flc;video/x-fli;video/x-flic;video/x-flv;video/x-m4v;video/x-matroska;video/x-mpeg;video/x-ms-asf;video/x-ms-asx;video/x-msvideo;video/x-ms-wm;video/x-ms-wmv;video/x-ms-wmx;video/x-ms-wvx;video/x-nsv;video/x-ogm+ogg;video/x-theora+ogg;video/x-totem-stream;audio/x-pn-realaudio;audio/3gpp;audio/ac3;audio/AMR;audio/AMR-WB;audio/basic;audio/midi;audio/mp2;audio/mp4;audio/mpeg;audio/ogg;audio/prs.sid;audio/vnd.rn-realaudio;audio/x-aiff;audio/x-ape;audio/x-flac;audio/x-gsm;audio/x-it;audio/x-m4a;audio/x-matroska;audio/x-mod;audio/x-mp3;audio/x-mpeg;audio/x-ms-asf;audio/x-ms-asx;audio/x-ms-wax;audio/x-ms-wma;audio/x-musepack;audio/x-pn-aiff;audio/x-pn-au;audio/x-pn-wav;audio/x-pn-windows-acm;audio/x-realaudio;audio/x-real-audio;audio/x-sbc;audio/x-speex;audio/x-tta;audio/x-wav;audio/x-wavpack;audio/x-vorbis;audio/x-vorbis+ogg;audio/x-xm;application/x-flac;
```

And exit nautilus:

```
nautilus -q
```

Go to you video and see the thumbnail preview appear for all videos.

Comment: If this does not work read the complete version here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/2608/nautilus-video-thumbnails-without-totem/115855#115855

Answer (score 1):

As of Vivid the only package needed is `ffmpegthumbnailer`:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ffmpegthumbnailer
```

And the lines to be replaced are only the `TryExec=[...]` and `Exec=[...]` lines (this is a one-liner to be executed from the command-line to replace both):

```
sudo sed -i 's/^TryExec=.*$/TryExec=ffmpegthumbnailer/; s/^Exec=.*$/Exec=ffmpegthumbnailer -s %s -i %i -o %o -c png -f -t 10/' /usr/share/thumbnailers/totem.thumbnailer
```

Then as usual one should close `nautilus` and remove the `~/.cache/thumbnails` folder:

```
nautilus -q && rm -r ~/.cache/thumbnails
```

Comment: Whatever happened to good old `sudo sed -i`?

Comment: @muru I didn't know that `sed` could edit in-place, thanks, updating it