# Green Thumbnails in Ubuntu Gnome 17.04

Tags: video, thumbnails, mkv

[My video (.mkv) thumbnails are green (or monochromatic)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/907607/my-video-mkv-thumbnails-are-green-or-monochromatic)

This didn't solve my problem, the situation is exactly the same, it used to work in 16.10 but it's not working now.

Is this a bug should I file a bug report?

[image: Screenshot]