# What rendering engine does Nautilus use to show HTML previews/thumbnails?

Tags: gnome, nautilus, previews, thumbnails

I just noticed that HTML files with CSS transforms on elements show *with* the CSS transforms within the thumbnails on Nautilus. So what rendering engine does Nautilus use to generate the thumbnails for HTML files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thumbnailing programs are installed separately except for text/plain and are specified in gconf here:

[image]

This system allows you install different programs to do the rendering of different kinds of images. My system doesn't have any html preview/thumnails and gconf reflects that. So I wonder what gnome packages you have installed that provide that functionality.

Comment: those are provided by some kind of gtk-html or mozilla/gtk integration related package to memory, but it is broken if you use newer versions of xulrunner unfortunately.

Comment: @Roland Taylor: could you elaborate on the "it is broken if you..." part?

Comment: the thumbnails do not show up. it either shows a white box, or a loading icon.

Comment: Thanks. However, even though I only quoted the first part of that statement, my emphasis was on the latter part, i.e. "... if you use newer versions of xulrunner".

Comment: - meaning, will it be affected only if I manually update xulrunner separately or if the one that comes with firefox is updated as well?

Answer (score 0):

Install gnome-web-photo

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-web-photo
```

If it doesn't work not open gconf-editor go to */desktop/gnome/thumbnailers/text@html*
and change the command

```
gnome-web-photo --mode=thumbnail --timeout=16 --size=%s %u %o
```

to

```
/usr/bin/gnome-web-photo --mode=thumbnail --timeout=16 --size=%s %u %o
```

Normally you can reload the view to get the thumbnails. If you want to recreate all icons see here: [Refresh thumbnails in nautilus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1057/refresh-thumbnails-in-nautilus/20122)