# How to view HTML files thumbnail preview in nautilus

Tags: nautilus, thumbnails

How can I view HTML files thumbnail preview in nautilus just like the previews for image and video files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [What rendering engine does Nautilus use to show HTML previews/thumbnails?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13648/what-rendering-engine-does-nautilus-use-to-show-html-previews-thumbnails), [Refresh thumbnails in nautilus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1057/refresh-thumbnails-in-nautilus) and [How I repaired my html thumbnails](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1238050) questions, I finally figured it out.

1. Install `gnome-web-photo` if you don't have it.
   `sudo apt-get install gnome-web-photo`
2. Clear thumbnail cache
   `rm -r  ~/.thumbnails`
   `killall nautilus`

Enjoy html thumbnails in nautilus.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In 2020, gnome-web-photo is unmaintained both by upstream, debian and Ubuntu maintainers, and is no longer in the repos.

This is how I got HTML thumbnails working in Ubuntu 19.10 and Nemo file manager:

`sudo apt-get install wkhtmltopdf`

```
cat << EOF | sudo tee /usr/bin/wkhtmltoimage-thumbnailer
#!/bin/sh

IN=$1
OUT=$2

TMP=$(mktemp).png

timeout 5s /usr/bin/wkhtmltoimage --disable-javascript --crop-h 800 "$IN" "$TMP"
mv $TMP "$OUT"
EOF
```

`sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/wkhtmltoimage-thumbnailer`

```
cat << EOF | sudo tee /usr/share/thumbnailers/wkhtmltoimage.thumbnailer
[Thumbnailer Entry]
TryExec=/usr/bin/wkhtmltoimage-thumbnailer
Exec=/usr/bin/wkhtmltoimage-thumbnailer %i %o
MimeType=text/html;
EOF
```

`rm ~/.cache/thumbnails/fail/gnome-thumbnail-factory/*`

`killall nemo`

Apart from wkhtmltoimage, `cutycapt` is another working HTML-to-image renderer currently in repos.