# Incorrect orientation of thumbnails in Nautilus ("Files") using 14.04

Tags: nautilus, files, thumbnails, rotate, orientation

In Files 3.10.1 (formerly Nautilus) I display thumbnails when viewing a folder of images. If the orientation of some images is wrong (i.e. landscape format displaying as portrait, or vice versa) I rotate the image to correct the orientation, and save the file when I close it. Sometimes the corrected orientation is represented by the thumbnail, but sometimes the thumbnail remains incorrect.

I have deleted ~/.thumbnails/fail

I have run rm -r  ~/.thumbnails

I have refreshed using F5

There is another odd symptom, which may help explain the problem to someone. Suppose I have an image that appears as a thumbnail wrongly oriented, rotated 90 degrees clockwise. So I open and rotate the image 90 degree counter-clockwise to correct the orientation. The thumbnail still displays with the wrong orientation, but when I open the image using Files it is correctly oriented. If I open it in GIMP, however, it has the wrong orientation. It seems as if Files has not really rotated the image file, but knows that it should *display* it rotated when it opens the image. (But GIMP does not know that it should display it this way).

Comment: The solutions described at http://askubuntu.com/questions/1057/refresh-thumbnails-in-nautilus do not work for me

Comment: Please edit your question to include which solutions you tried and how your results differed from what you expected. Thank you!

Comment: I suggest you carefully review the answer by Javier Rivera.

Comment: I strongly suspect that this has to do with EXIF data. Nautilus auto-rotates images that have their orientation saved on their EXIF data if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: You could well be right, Hakermania. But in that case there is a weird discrepancy between what Files/Nautilus (and GIMP) sees as the correct way to show the image, and what Image Viewer sees to be the correct way. Any ideas, anyone?