# Thumbnails do not update after modifying jpg file with Gimp

Tags: 16.04, nautilus, 16.10, gimp, thumbnails

I regularly modify `jpg` images using GIMP (currently in version 2.8).  However, the thumbnail in Nautilus (currently in version 3.14.3) does not change/update after the modification.  I find this highly unusual and annoying as there are many files to be changed and it is hard to quickly tell which ones I have done and which one I have not.  Of course, I can use the date field instead but the behaviour continues to be annoying.

I am very aware of some workarounds.  That is, I can delete the `.cache/thumbnails` as one of the solutions provided here: [Refresh thumbnails in nautilus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1057/refresh-thumbnails-in-nautilus) but it would be much better for this to be done automatically so I do not have to waste time later every time I open any other folder and all the thumbnails are generated again.  Note that the solution in the same page suggesting to use `touch *` or `touch filename.jpg` does not work.

Anyone knows what is causing this or how to fix it?

[I have two computers, one running 16.04 and the other running 16.10, the behaviour is the same on both.]

Answer (score 0):

Old subject... But to keep track of my conclusion and workaround (and make them available to the world ;) ), here they are:

For me, deleting .cache/thumbnails/* folders, was not sufficient to update my jpgs' thumbnails (in thunar and eog). In fact, the thumbnail which is not updated is the (EXIF's) one embedded inside the jpg file (not the one from the .cache/thumbnails/ folder).

The way I found to update a bunch of jpgs is to open the folder containing jpgs with gThumb, then "Select all" (Ctrl+a) the jpgs, and eventually Tools -> Rotate Physically. I'm not sure what this function actually do (maybe something with the EXIF rotation info), but it updates each image EXIF/embedded thumbnail.

Comment: Thank you for following up.  What you offer is another workaround though in that what I referred to in my original question was that the default behaviour should be to automatically change the thumbnail if the file has changed, i.e., not forcing the change.