# Ubuntu 17.10 - Problems displaying thumbnails in Nautilus in XOrg

Tags: nautilus, xorg, 17.10, thumbnails, wayland

Hi just installed a fresh 17.10, gnome shell. Wayland was not working out for me (it was slower than xorg and a couple of important apps weren't running well on it) so I switched back to XOrg session.

Almost everything is running smoothly with the single exception of Nautilus which is no longer displaying the thumbnails on any of the image files. Preferences are already set to Always show thumbnails and the maximum file size is jacked up to 4GB.  The thumbnails display perfectly when I'm in Wayland but dissapear in XOrg.

Can any suggest how I can go about fixing this or point me in the direction of a solution?

Comment: Have you tried [refreshing the thumbnail cache](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1057/refresh-thumbnails-in-nautilus)?

Answer (score 0):

Seems it was a permission issue, I have files in my home folder that were owned by the root account.

I had just installed the OS and hadn't setup my gui pkexec policy for nautilus or gedit and I was a little lazy and started up nautilus from terminal using sudo. I remember finding it weird that sudo nautilus was loading my non-root user settings, it must have overwritten the thumbnail cache with a root owned one. This must be a recent change,  didn't used to do this in the past. When you started a nautilus session (even with sudo via terminal), it used to use the root directory for settings.

Ah well, I guess I'm going to be avoiding sudo for GUI altogether from now on. It's weird that the thumbnails managed to display ok in Wayland.

Comment: [Why should users never use normal sudo to start graphical applications?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270006/why-should-users-never-use-normal-sudo-to-start-graphical-applications)

Comment: Why, I just spent half an hour writing you an answer until I realized that you weren't asking me a question but posting a link to a question...

Comment: Orange coloured text is the clue ;-)

Comment: Not at 4AM it wasn't... :) Thanks for the link, though, it was very informative.