# I am using ubuntu 17.10 and many types of files as .png .pdf .mp3 and more shows the unspecified Icon in nautilus. How can I fix that?

Tags: nautilus, icons, 17.10

Even after downloading and installing icon packages this problem still remains as you can see in the picture[image]

Comment: Have you tried this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1057/refresh-thumbnails-in-nautilus?

Comment: Those aren't "unspecified" icons, but the temporary icon used to indicate thumbnail rendering is in progress. There may be a bug which causes thumbnail rendering to not complete, which can be caused by something like Dropbox syncing the files while you are currently viewing the directory.