# Caja running and can not kill it, Ubuntu 18.04 Mate

Tags: process, caja

Caja runs constantly and restarts after I kill it, using 10-20% cpu on each of 4 cores.
If I stop it (but do not kill it) all is fine. When it runs the hard disk is constantly running as well. 
What is going on. Why can I not kill it and why is it reading the hd all the time on its own???
This started after I accepted the last update today... (don't remember what it contained)

Comment: Forgot to mention it started an unnamed process that started and disappeared with new PID every 5-10 seconds.

Comment: It is possible that this is caused by thumbnail generator of Caja. See similar [problem with Nautilus](https://askubuntu.com/a/20122/66509).

Comment: Then I can recommend to ask on MATE-friendly https://ubuntu-mate.community/ .

Comment: Yes it seems to have something to do with a process called by Caja: atril-thumbnail. But even when I delete all the failed thumbnails as suggested it does not make any difference.

Comment: Thanks, I have made a support request in the Mate community.