# Can't get exe-thumbnailer to work

Tags: 20.04, nautilus, executable

I'm running 20.04 and installed exe-thumbnailer and its dependencies in the Synaptic package manager but the thumbnails don't show up in the file explorer.

Comment: Try refreshing your thumbnails - https://askubuntu.com/questions/1057/refresh-thumbnails-in-nautilus

Comment: @Parto i refreshed them but they still come up as the default exe thumbnail.